# Find files that contain a string but NOT on the correct line

Tags: grep, sed

From a given directory, I'm looking to determine which files:

1. contain `pattern`
2. but NOT on line 1

I know how to do part 1—`grep -nHRF [pattern] [path]`—however, I'm looking to filter based on the ones that match the `pattern`, but do not appear on line 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
grep -n 'pattern' path | grep -v ':1:'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` with an address range:

```
sed -n '2,/pattern/p' file
```

which will print on line matching the `pattern` starting from the 2nd line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -nHRF pattern path` but without line 1, with GNU sed, would be:

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
for f in path/**; do
    sed -n '1n; /pattern/{F;=;p}' "$f"
done | paste -d: - - -
```

You need to iterate over the files, otherwise `=` will output the cumulative line number from all the lines of all the files, and `1n` would only match for the first line of the first file.